# ¿Cómo podría comprobar que un string compuesto por cada i e i+1 esté en otro data frame y si sí retorne la suma/concatenación?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Quisiera saber cómo comprobar que la suma (o concantenación) de un dato y su contiguo en formato string (o de texto) perteneciente a un df esté en otro df, y en tal caso me concatene las palabras que sí estén. Es decir, que si la composición de cada i con i+1 en tabla1 está en tabla2 obtenga lo de tabla3. Intenté haciendo un antijoin pero no pude, no sé mucho.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla1

| id | palabra |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | no |
| 0 | podré |
| 0 | hoy |
| 1 | sí |
| 1 | es |
| 1 | posible |

Tabla2

| compuesto |
| --- |
| no podré |
| es posible |

Tabla3

| id | palabra |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | no_podré |
| 0 | hoy |
| 1 | sí |
| 1 | es_posible |

Comment: has utilizado el método `.isin()`??

Comment: Sí pero solo sé para elementos individuales o en tal caso del mismo df , no sabría como aplicarlo en un for para que me haga todo el recorrido en los df. Gracias

Comment: podrías colocar tus dataframes como texto por favor? así se me facilitará trabajar en una respuesta

Comment: Dale, ya lo hago, soy nuevo y no sé ponerlos jajaj, pero ya voy

Comment: Creo que ya, o te refieres a crear cada base como csv y subirlo?

Comment: así esta bien..

Comment: Lo siento, ya es hora de dormir,btal vez mañana publique la respuesta. Espero que abulafia o patricio moracho te respondan pronto

Comment: No entiendo por qué en el dataframe de resultados (Tabla 3) aparece "hoy" y "si". Esas palabras no cumplen con la especificación. Para empezar no resultan de concatenar dos filas seguidas de Tabla 1, y para seguir no se encuentran en Tabla 2.

Comment: @abulafia Son los que  quedan después de cubrir la condición. O sea, deja los que no la cumplen y en las que cumple pues hace la transformación

Comment: @Christian jajaj nadie me ayudó, de casualidad no sabes cómo ? por fa me sería de bastante ayuda

Comment: Malos momentos ahora, ando en una fiesta.  En cuento pueda vuelvo a retomar la solución que estaba haciendo

Comment: @Christian Probablemente lo olvidaste jajaja, o no sé, pero pos quería preguntarte si si lo lograste, eres como mi salvación en este momento jajaja

Comment: Ha! perdón, me enfoqué mucho en mi proyecto, ahora mismo trato de ver tu problema y te mantengo al tanto

Comment: Haber, para el segundo y tercer elemento de la tabla uno sale `podré hoy` y so no se encuentra en la tabla 2, por qué en la tabla 3 se guarda `hoy`?? Hay algún procedimiento que hacer en caso el dato no se encuentre en la segunda tabla??

Comment: Creo que ya lo tengo, pero necesito la confirmación del comentario anterior

Comment: @Christian Porque la idea es mantener las palabras individuales que no aparecen en la tabla 2 junto los compuestos . Es decir, sería algo tipo  si el i+(i+1)  de la tabla 1 no aparece en tabla 2, dejar el i, si el i+(i+1) está en tabla 2 dejar ese i+(i+1),hablando de strings o ese texto...eso para cada i supongo.Gracias

Comment: entonces ya lo tengo, espera un momento mientras escribo la respuesta!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para hacer lo que quieres tendremos que crear una función que se encargue de ese trabajo. Para poder obtener la concatenación o la palabra que no está tendremos que transformar los datos en "conjuntos" y hacer operaciones de conjuntos, como lo es la diferencia.

En python no existen los conjuntos pero si podemos aplicar las operaciones en los `set` que son un tipo de dato representados así: `{val1, val2, val3}`, sus elementos son únicos.

Para poder obtener la palabra que no está entre otras 2 tan solo debemos convertir a `set` cada dato y restar, por ejemplo `{"hola", "mundo"} - {"mundo"}` dará `{"hola"}`.

Para hacer esta conversión usaremos un ciclo `for` y el método `apply` para poder aplicarle una transformación a ciertos datos.

```py
def create_df_from_coincidences(df1, df2, **kwargs)->pd.DataFrame:
    data=[]
    for i in range(len(df1)-1):
        word_1 = df1.loc[i, "palabra"]
        word_2 = df1.loc[i+1, "palabra"]

        if any(df2.loc[:,"compuesto"].isin([f"{word_1} {word_2}"])):
            data.append(f"{word_1}_{word_2}")
        else:
            word_encountered = sorted([{word_1, word_2}- word_table for word_table in df2.loc[:,"compuesto"].apply(lambda x: set(x.split(" ")))])
            if len(word_encountered[0])==1:
                data+=list(word_encountered[0])

    return pd.DataFrame(data, **kwargs)
```

Esta función toma como argumento 2 dataframes, se itera en el rango de `0` hasta `len(df)-1`  debido a que iremos comprando `i concatenado con i+1` y al llegar al último nos pasaremos del rango, por eso iteramos hasta `len(df)-1`.  Luego accedemos al contenido de esas celdas, es decir a `i` e `i+1` y guardamos esos datos, luego concatenamos esos datos y usamos `isin` para verificar si están contenido en alguna parte del segundo dataframe (tabla 2). Aquí usamos la función `any` pues al usar `ìsin` se nos devuelve una serie con valores booleanos (no solo uno) y al usar un condicional con una serie de booleanos pandas entra en conflicto ya que no sabe a que dato te refieres, por eso usamos `any` para verificar que por lo menos 1 dato sea `True`. En caso la concatenación de las 2 palabras no esté, entonces tendremos que hallar la palabra que no está, para ello convertimos cada elemento del DataFrame 2 en un `set` y hallamos la diferencia, luego simplemente guardamos el dato.

Para tu ejemplo he recreado tus DataFrames y los he usado con mi función.

```py
cols = ["id", "palabra"]
data =[
       [0, "no"],
       [0, "podré"],
       [0, "hoy"],
       [1, "sí"],
       [1, "es"],
       [1, "posible"]
]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
cols2=["compuesto"]

data2 = [
         ["no podré"],
         ["es posible"]
]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=cols2)


final = create_df_from_coincidences(df1, df2)
```

La función también recibe argumentos variables y estos argumentos adicionales son para pandas, donde puedes especificar datos adicionales de como quieres que quede tu dataframe, puedes agregar nombre a la columna o indices, recuerda que esto debe ser acorde a pandas, pues todo esto lo realiza pandas.  Por tanto podemos escribir:

```py
final = create_df_from_coincidences(df1, df2, columns=["datas"], index=[1,2,3,4])
```

Y obtendremos:

|  | datas |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | no_podré |
| 2 | hoy |
| 3 | sí |
| 4 | es_posible |

Comment: Holaa,muchas gracias por todo, me salvaste. Voy a ver si no presento inconvenientes aplicando esta gran solución, gracias de nuevo (voté bien la respuesta pero como soy nuevo no la toma, no sé si eso te importe mucho)

Comment: me importa más haberte ayudado y que no te hayas quedado estancado. Cualquier inconveniente que tengas me lo haces saber y te ayudaré en lo posible

Comment: Me sirvió mucho, muchas muchas gracias. Tengo una duda que de pronto sabes, cómo podría hacer para que  el index con el que sale la tabla 3 sean la de los  de tabla 1( lo que se llama id). y pues si es un compuesto( la suma de las dos palabras) sea el id del primer elemento del compuesto

Comment: Si se puede, en cuanto pueda edito la respuesta